# How do I write a hook around mercurial's "push creates new remote head"?

Tags: bash, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I want to make a hook that when someone is pushing to the remote, if they get the `abort: push creates new remote head` error message, the hook will try to merge the remote and local head (if easy merge i.e. no conflicting files) and push again.

How can I do this? I tried adding a hook on `pre-push`, but I don't know how to get just the remote's head hash for the current branch.

Here is what I have been trying, though it is not polished.

```sh
currbranch=$(hg branch)
hg pull
numheads=$(hg heads --template "." $currbranch)
if test ${#numheads} -gt 1; then
    echo "Merge needed."
    head1=$(hg heads --template "{node}\n" $currbranch | head -n 1)
    head2=$(hg heads --template "{node}\n" $currbranch | tail -n 1)
    overlap=$((hg status --change $head1 --no-status ; hg status --change $head2 --no-status) | sort | uniq --repeated)
    if [ -z "$overlap" ]; then
        echo "Attempting automatic merge..."
        hg merge "$head1"  # Fails when merging the wrong head
        hg merge "$head2"  # But how do we know which one is wrong?
        hg commit -m "Merge"
        echo "Completed."
    else
        echo "Cannot automatically merge"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

To be clear, what doesn't work ahead is merging both heads. How can I know which head is local and which head is remote?

Also, is this the right hook to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can *try* to add and use [remotenames extension](https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgremotenames/src/default/) (it's rather old and not actively maintained since 2018, but may work) in order to have all remote peers **named in your repo** (in this case you'll know names of remote head(s) after pull)
2. You can (before pull) check presence of head in incoming set of changesets, smth. like

`hg in -r "head()" -T "{node|short}\n"` (TBT!)